# Solving Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am trying to assign value to the sharedPreference

```
sharedPreferences.setString('destination', 'supermarket');
```

But I'm having the following error.

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at
> character 1)
>
> E/flutter ( 3073): supermarket

Comment: Just for the sake of ruling this out, didn't you copy-paste the value from somewhere an invisible whitespace character could come before the 's'?

Comment: Uhm no. I even changed it to other values and I got the same error :(

Comment: Did you get instance of SharedPreferences. like this-    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

Comment: @Babul yes that's how I get it

Comment: Perhaps you need to change the value of `<newest version>` in `pubspec.yaml` per [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/key-value#1-add-the-dependency)?